# Export docx from Google Drive and convert to base64

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to export DOCX files from Google Drive.

```
gapi.client.drive.files.export({ fileId: id, alt: 'media', mimeType: _mimeType }).then((_response) => {
                var fileType = _response.headers['content-type'];
                var base64 = new Buffer(_response.body, 'utf8').toString('base64');
                var dataURI = 'data:' + fileType + ';base64,' + base64;
```

I send it to `https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`:

```
mimeType: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
alt: media
key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It works for images, for example, but Word shows `The file is corrupt and cannot be open`.

I think something wrong with `base64`.

How can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to open a file on FE to make sure it's not a BE issue:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
                var out = new Blob([_response.body], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    window.location.href = reader.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(out);
```

Result - `The file is corrupt and cannot be open`

**MY FINAL SOLUTION:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + id + '/export?alt=media&mimeType=' + _mimeType, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.access_token);
            xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
            xhr.onload = () => {
                var base64 = 'data:' + _mimeType +';base64,' + this.base64ArrayBuffer(xhr.response);
                resolve(base64);
            }
            xhr.send();
```

`base64ArrayBuffer` is from https://gist.github.com/jonleighton/958841

Comment: What are you doing with the `data:` URI?

Comment: handle in PHP. `$f = fopen($output_file, 'wb');$data = explode(',', _post['file']);fwrite($f, base64_decode($data[1]));fclose($f)`

Comment: Then why are you making a `data:` URI at all?

Comment: @SLaks, I'm trying a lot of solutions. It's one of them. I tried `var blob = new Blob([_response.body], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" });var reader = new FileReader();reader.readAsDataURL(blob);reader.onloadend = function () { let base64data = reader.result;}` Same result

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this workaround? Also in my environment, `gapi.client.drive.files.export` didn't work. So I use XMLHttpRequest with `xhr.responseType = "blob"`.

#### Sample script :

```
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
var id = "### fileId ###";
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + id + "&format=docx&access_token=" + accessToken;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {

    console.log(reader.result); // dataURI

  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.response);
};
xhr.send();
```

#### Reference :

- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's only way, I think. I was able to do it with `XMLHttpRequest` and `responseType : arraybuffer` and `https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + id + '/export?alt=media&mimeType=' + _mimeType` URL

Comment: @Nick Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your issue was solved.