# “The validation of the PDF file failed.” When trying to send a generated PDF via email - DocuSign

Tags: node.js, pdf, docusignapi

We have some code which downloads a PDF file from Google Drive using the Drive API, after that we use the file to build a new envelope and send it to the customer.

Using the same file, some of these requests work, and some come back with an error "PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED".

I have the log([file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o13wGvDjY58kc3iLkm8rM_lk1aclKEx6/view?usp=sharing)) file which contains the base64 of the file and the request information, using an external tool to convert the base64 to PDF it seems to be valid and also I tried to open the file using Adobe acrobat and the document appears fine.

Is there any documentation on what makes a pdf invalid?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you try to manually upload it from the web app, not via the API, does that work? or do you get the same error?

Comment: I did a test using the web application and the same file and it works, it allowed me to upload the file, not sure why the api says it is invalid.

Comment: The PDF in your request is incomplete. DocuSign correctly returns PDF_VALIDATION_FAILED.

Comment: what external tool do you use to convert to base64?
You can always use binary upload instead of base64, maybe you have an encoding issue.

Comment: I tried using binary transfer instead of base64 encoding and I got the same error, following the doc instructions [link](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/send-binary/). The [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NpfxgFVxr29W_AOCdAZDpf3TNvSVLsma/view?usp=sharing)  file displays the same error so I think that some kind of validation rule is preventing the pdf from being uploaded (Sometimes it works).

Comment: Looks like there's a file issue to me. I opened your log, copied the base64, decoded it, and saved it as file.pdf. That file would neither open in Foxit Reader nor upload to the DocuSign web console. For one, it's missing `%%EOF` at the end, but there are likely other issues that make it not a PDF.

Comment: I was thinking that too but I tested the base64 on this [tool](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf) and decoded it and the file seems to be fine I also used this [website](https://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf20/en/products/pdf-converter-validation/pdf-validator/?gclid=CjwKCAiAoOz-BRBdEiwAyuvA63FHP1r-bj3gD1WJzQR2Os-SSdBusXVsfgNi3A6bk_Ll1otBpwn8KBoCnFIQAvD_BwE) to validate the file and it says its okay. I use Nodejs to read file `const fileBytes = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  const doc2b64 = Buffer.from(fileBytes).toString('base64');`

Comment: *"decoded it and the file seems to be fine"* - I don't know what exactly you have decoded but the PDFs in the requests you shared (from 16:35:20 and from 23:30:48 yesterday) are both cut off. The first one is 61761 bytes long (but should have been 62353 bytes long) and the second is 52067 bytes long (but should have been 55913 bytes long).

Comment: Yes my bad. The encoding of the files was the problem. I was downloading the files from Drive using the Drive API and I was setting the response type to stream so I changed it to arrayBuffer and then base64 and now it works now. This other question helped me resolve my issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516262/export-docx-from-google-drive-and-convert-to-base64) Thank you all for your time and responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upload the file to a DocuSign envelope using the DocuSign web app, but it doesn't work when you use the API:

1. If the file type is not pdf then include the file extension in the `name` attribute. Eg **contract.docx**. The `fileExtension` attribute is somethimes not used by the platform.
2. You have a problem with your Base64 encoding method. Modify one of the [DocuSign code examples](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to send your file and it will work.

Comment: Yes you were right. The encoding of the files was the problem. I was downloading the files from Drive using the Drive API and I was setting the response type to stream so I changed it to arrayBuffer and then base64 and now it works. This other question helped me resolve my issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516262/export-docx-from-google-drive-and-convert-to-base64) Thank you Larry!

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up and the check! Glad it's working for you!